# How do I click things with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, tampermonkey, notice

I am on a website and I want to click 3 buttons using tampermonkey. How would I go about doing this. I know very little about tampermonkey.

Comment: first and most important aspect of doing something the first time : documentation

Comment: have a look at this tutorial http://hibbard.eu/tampermonkey-tutorial/